# Why when I print a python statement, ( ) gets printed as well?

Tags: python

```
    if len(all_stalls) == 0:
        print("No stalls found with given keywords.")

    # Print all stalls that match the keywords
    else:
        print ("Food Stalls Found:", len(all_stalls))
```

Output: ('Food Stalls Found:', 10)
==> why are there brackets around?

Comment: Are you in Python2?

Comment: In Python 2, `print` is not a function; you are executing a `print` statement whose first expression is a tuple, and the string representation of a `tuple` includes the parentheses.

Comment: check your python version by running `python -V`. If you have 2 versions(2.x and 3.x) of python installed you can also try running the program by `python3 <insert program name here>`

Comment: Obligatory suggestion: stop using Python 2, and start using Python 3. This type of question indicates you are just learning Python, and so have no vested interest in legacy Python 2 code.

Answer (score 1):

You are in python2.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X530FN-S530FN:~$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print ("Food Stalls Found:", 10)
('Food Stalls Found:', 10)
>>> 
[2]+  Stopped                 python
ubuntu@ubuntu-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X530FN-S530FN:~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print ("Food Stalls Found:", 10)
Food Stalls Found: 10
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 2 where print is not a function. And when you call it like that with `()`, it gets interpreted as tuple.

So, either you use

```py
print "Food Stalls Found:", len(all_stalls)
```

or:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
print ("Food Stalls Found:", len(all_stalls))
```